# Page can't be found when storing/submitting form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem regarding laravel routes. My code is working yesterday but today isn't. When I Submit the form it returns

> **ERROR: page can't be found**.

I have already change the form action attribute to the URL indicated in the routes. but the problem still persists.

```
Route::get('/products', 'Client\ProductController@index');

Route::get('/products/create-step1', 'Client\ProductController@createStep1');
Route::post('/products/create-step1', 'Client\ProductController@postCreateStep1');

Route::get('/products/create-step2', 'Client\ProductController@createStep2');
Route::post('/products/create-step2', 'Client\ProductController@postCreateStep2');

Route::get('/products/create-step3', 'Client\ProductController@createStep3');
Route::post('/products/create-step3', 'Client\ProductController@postCreateStep3');
Route::get('/products/create-step4', 'Client\ProductController@createStep4');
Route::post('/products/store', 'Client\ProductController@store')->name('store');
```

Here is my routes.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail(1);
    $transact = new Transaction();
    $transact->transact = $transact->generateTransaction();
    $transact->status_id = 1;
    $transact->client_id = $client->id;
    $transact->save();
    if($request->session()->get('quote1')){
        for($x = 1 ; $x<20; $x++){
            if($request->session()->get('quote'.$x)){
                $quote = $request->session()->get('quote'.$x);
                $rfq = new Quotation();
                $rfq->requestQuote($quote, $transact);
            }
        }
    }
    $origin = $request->session()->get('origin');
    $origin->transaction_id = $transact->id;
    $goods = $request->session()->get('goods');
    $goods->transaction_id = $transact->id;
    $dest = $request->session()->get('dest');
    $dest->transaction_id = $transact->id;

    if(!(($origin->save()) && ($dest->save()) && ($goods->save()))){

        return view('errors.503');
    }else{
        $request->session()->flush();
        return redirect('/Main');
    }

}
```

Here is my Controller

```
 <form action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST">

  //content of my form with submit button



 </form>
```

Comment: Do you have a Route that handles your `redirect("/Main")`?

Comment: Are you sure it's on the form submit and not when it's redirecting to `/Main`?

Comment: yes i have a route handling the /Main url. and it specifically displaying an error message involving the /products/store. Error message : No webpage was found for the web address: http://jslogisticsph.test/products/store

Comment: thank you for giving me a hint @TimLewis

Answer (score 0):

Try to run routes list command to see if your route is listed:

```
php artisan route:list
```

If no, your route file is wrong.

Or maybe is a route cache problem, if so you can clear it with this:

```
php artisan route:clear
```